# How to preserve the &quot; in an inbound XML file through XSLT and ANT

Tags: xslt, ant

This problem has been driving me crazy today.

(note I've added spaced to stop the characters being encoded below)

In an input XML file I have html text like "& lt;li class=& quot;classname& quot;& gt;"

The input file is correctly encoded for our needs.

The trouble is I'm running it though an XSLT to transform the XML into a CSV. Everything was okay for the & lt; & gt;, but the XSLT is outputting the & quot; as '"'. So I finally resorted to the xslt segment below to try to replace the embedded quotes back to & quot;.

I couldn't figure out how to get the xslt to replace the quotes with & quot;, so, because I'm already using ant for the xslt processing, I thought it would be easier to use ANT replace to replace the '\"' with & quot; after the xslt task.

Now I'm going crazy, because ANT is also expanding & quot; and replacing the \" with "!!!

So parts to the question:
1. Is there a way to preserve the & quot; during the xslt transform. (best)
2. If not is there a way to string replace the " with & quot; from the xslt?
3. If neither of them work, what's the syntax to get ANT to output & quot; instead of " (i.e escape the entity)

**ANT**

```
<replace file="${dataload.dataDir}/inbound/products/wc_store_locator.csv" token='\"' value="&quot;" />
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:call-template name="replace-quotes">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="notificationMessage"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'\&quot;'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>

      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace-quotes">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-quotes">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah never mind, I figured out the ant syntax:

it was:
        & amp;quot;

Answer (score 0):

Doing a replace of " by `&quot;` using a process that isn't XML-aware seems crazy - it will replace all the attribute-delimiting quotes as well as those appearing within text content.

When I see this kind of question my immediate reaction is to challenge the requirement. Why are you trying to do this? Why do you need quotes to be escaped, when an XML parser doesn't require them to be escaped? Are you reading the XML with something that isn't a true XML parser, and if so why? If you don't want to use XML properly, is it wise to use it at all?

Comment: We were using an XML loader that ships with a product we're implementing. I recently switched the interface to CSV to be more consistent with the rest of the batch. But the source system team can't produce the CSV for a few weeks, so I've temporarily written an XSLT to transform the XML into the CSV which we'll use until the source can produce the CSV. The encoding is in the file because we're importing HTML as part of some text fields, but it's otherwise database content. Encoding the HTML was easier than fiddling with escaping quotes etc.

Comment: Also, the XSLT transforms the quotes to \" for only specific fields, and then ANT replaces occurrences of \" with & quot; so there's no risk of global replacement with this approach. I would have preferred the xslt to write out the & quot; directly....